# get particular job details based on jobId in redux and router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

i have list of jobs for different job id. i have to fetch the particular job details based on job id. I have created action and reducer function for that. But, i am new to redux not able to understand how to connect this with component and display the result.

i am calling the api by axios to get the job details on particular id. I am not aware of how to make the call into the component. Now, I am getting undefined jobId.

action.js

```
export const retrieveLocations = (jobId) => (dispatch) => {
  axios.get(retrieveUrl+'/jobs/'+jobId).then(res => {
      dispatch({
          type: RETRIEVE_LOCATION,
          payload: res.data.jobs.basicDetails
      });
  });
};
```

reducer code:

```
case 'RETRIEVE_LOCATION':
            return{
                ...state,
                conLocations:action.payload
            }
```

component code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import store from '../../stores/store';
import {removeLocation,retrieveLocations} from '../../actions/locationActions';
import {removeAllLocation} from '../../actions/locationActions'

let _labels;

class ConfiguredLocation extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.handleRemove = this.handleRemove.bind(this);
        this.clearall = this.clearall.bind(this);
    }


    handleRemove(mruCode){
       this.props.removeLocation(mruCode)
    }

    clearall (){
      this.props.removeAllLocation()
    }
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
        let currJobId = this.props.match.params.jobId;
        let prevJobId = prevProps.match.params.jobId;
        if(currJobId!==prevJobId){
            this.props.retrieveLocations(jobId);
        }
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        let {jobId} = this.props.match.params;
        this.props.retrieveLocations(jobId);
        console.log(this.props);
    }

    render(){
        const _labels = store.getLabels();
        const {conLocations} = this.props;
        return(
            <div className="col-padding">
              <div className="pos-div"><h3>Configured Location</h3><button className="allLargeBtn" onClick={()=>{this.clearall()}}>Remove all location</button></div><hr/>
               <table className="table">
                    <tbody>
                        {conLocations.map((loct,index)=><tr key={index}>
                           <td><h5>{loct.mruCode} - {_labels[loct.division]} - {loct.country}</h5></td>
                           <td className="text-right"><img alt="DeleteIcon" onClick={()=>this.handleRemove(loct.mruCode)}className="deleteIconStyle" src="img/delete_large_active.png" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        )}
                    </tbody>
               </table>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

const mapStateToProps = state =>{
    return {
        conLocations: state.locationRed.conLocations
    };
  };

  const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) =>{
      return{
          removeLocation: (mruCode)=>{dispatch(removeLocation(mruCode))},
          removeAllLocation: () =>{dispatch(removeAllLocation())},
          retrieveLocations:(jobId) =>{dispatch(retrieveLocations(jobId))}
      };
  };


export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(withRouter(ConfiguredLocation));
```

Route code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory} from 'react-router-dom';
import { Security, ImplicitCallback, SecureRoute } from 'something...';
import history from '../history';
import store from '../stores/store';
import ConfiguredLocation from '../components/location/ConfiguredLocation';

/*Custom components imported */
import AppFrame from './views/AppFrame';

import {something...} from '../env-to-local';

class AppNavigator extends React.Component {

    constructor( props ) {
        super( props );
        this.state = {
            loading: true
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        var self = this;
        setTimeout(() => {
            self.setState({ loading: false });
        }, 1000);
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.loading) {
            return (
                <div className="fix"><i className="fa fa-2x fa-circle fa-spin"></i>
                    <div>Loading</div>
                </div>
            )
        } else {
            return (                    
                <Router history={history}>
                   <div>
                    <Security issuer={soething...}
                        client_id={something...}
                        redirect_uri={window.location.origin + '/app/callback'}
                        scope={['profile', 'openid']}>
                        <Route path='/callback' component={ImplicitCallback} />
                        <AppFrame />
                    </Security>
                    <Route exact path="/app/jobs/:jobId" component={ConfiguredLocation}/>
                    </div>
                </Router>
            );
        }
    }
};

module.exports = AppNavigator;
```

store code:

```
<Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
            <AppNavigator />
        </Provider>
```

While checking in console, i am getting this empty array and this.[image: undefined error]

Please suggest me on this. how to display jobs from api based on id

Comment: Your code seems to be correct barring the fact that, you will need to initialise `conLocations` in reducer initialState to empty array and also that you need to make a call to `retrieveLocations` if the params changed.

Comment: you can inspect redux store using react dev tools (or redux tools) ... maybe your `mapStateToProps` should be `conLocations: state.conLocations` ?

Comment: Can you show us your `combineReducer` function ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to asynchronous function like axios call with redux, you should use middleware like `redux-saga` or `redux-thunk` and so on.

I'll give you some example for using `redux-thunk`

#### make store

```
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from <your rootReducer path>

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(
    thunkMiddleware
)(createStore);

const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(rootReducer);
```

#### action.js

```
export const retrieveLocations = (jobId) => (dispatch) => {
  axios.get(urlLoc+'/jobs/'+jobId).then(res => {
      dispatch({
          type: RETRIEVE_LOCATION,
          payload: res.data.job.locations
      });
  });
};
```

Comment: store is fine. because it is working fine for retrieve all location. You have any suggestions to get item details by id

Comment: Do you have jobId list? Or, can you fetch it somewhere?

Comment: `job: {parts: null, pricingDetails: null, laborAndResources: null,…}
basicDetails: {jobCodeId: 55299, jobId: 87995, createdBy: "HB83956", createdDate: null, deleteFlag: false,…}`  this type of array json is shwoing. I have edited the result data in actions( payload: res.data.job.basicDetails) ... if you have any suggestions how to render this into component . job is the root and basicDetails is the child

Comment: i am getting the undefined error for jobid. Is this error regarding my Route?