# hide the button after clicking inside map function -Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have multiple location info list with add button each of that location item. I want to hide that 'add location' button after adding operation. Only particular add button  should be hided after clicking not all add button in that list

i have tried with button state true and false using setState and disabled. But it is disabling all the button in that list. I am using redux to add operation. I don't know how to do that part for unique location id

action for add opeartion:

```
export const addLocation = mruCode =>({
  type: ADD_LOCATION,
  payload:mruCode
});
```

action code for add all location:

```
export const addAllLocation = () =>({
    type : ALL_LOCATION
  });
```

reducer code for add all location:

```
case 'ALL_LOCATION':
            return{
                ...state,
                conLocations:[...state.location]
            }
```

reducer for add opeartion:

```
case 'ADD_LOCATION':
  let addedLoc = state.location.find(obj=>(obj.mruCode === action.payload))
  return{
    ...state,
    conLocations: [...state.conLocations,addedLoc]
  };
```

Component full code:

```
export class NewLocationPanel extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
               open:false,
               disableButton:-1
        };
        this.togglePanel = this.togglePanel.bind(this);
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        this.allLocations = this.allLocations.bind(this);
    }
    togglePanel (e){
        this.setState({open : !this.state.open});
    }
    handleClick (mruCode){
        return this.props.addLocation(mruCode);
     }
     allLocations (){
       return this.props.addAllLocation();
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.loadData();
      }
    render(){
        const _labels = store.getLabels();
        let collapsedToggle = this.props.open ? 'collapsed' : ''
        return(
            <div className="panel panel-default">
            <div className="panel-heading" onClick={(e)=>this.togglePanel(e)}>
              <div className="row">
              <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-lg-6 panelHeadingLabel">
                     <span>{this.props.title}</span>
                     </div>
                        <div className="pull-right">
                        <span className="defaultHeaderTextColor">{this.props.location.map((loc,index)=>loc.primary===true ? (<span>{loc.mruCode} - {_labels[loc.division]} - {loc.country}</span>):null)}
                           <span onClick={(e)=>this.togglePanel(e)} className={this.state.open ? "collapse-chevronn" : "collapse-chevron"} aria-hidden="true"></span>
                   </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
           </div>
              {this.state.open?(
                        <div className="panel-body">
                             <div className="row grid-divider">
                             <div className="col-sm-6">
                             <div className="col-padding"><div className="pos-div"><h3>Locations List</h3><button className="allLargeBtn" onClick={()=>{this.allLocations()}}>Add all locations</button></div><hr/>
                             {this.props.location.map((item,index)=>(
                             <div key={index}><div><b>{item.mruCode} - {_labels[item.division]} - {item.country}</b>{!this.props.conLocations.includes(item.mruCode)&&(<div className="pull-right jd"><button className="call-to-action" onClick={()=>{this.handleClick(item.mruCode)}}>Add Location</button></div>)}<hr/></div></div>))}
                            </div>
                             </div> 
                                  <div className="col-sm-6">
                                   <div><ConfiguredLocation/></div>
                                  </div>
                                  </div> 
                    </div>):null}

            </div>

        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state =>{
    return{
        location:state.locationRed.location,
        conLocations:state.locationRed.conLocations
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return{
        loadData:()=>{dispatch(loadData())},
        addLocation:(mruCode)=>{dispatch(addLocation(mruCode))},
        addAllLocation:() =>{dispatch(addAllLocation())}
    }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(NewLocationPanel);
```

mruCode is primary unique id. particular add button should be hided after clicking. Please suggest me how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you have a list of buttons corresponding to locations, and you want to hide the buttons that have already been clicked. Right now your component doesn't have the list of already added locations, so you'll first need to pass that through in `mapStateToProps`

```
const mapStateToProps = state =>{
    return{
        location:state.locationRed.location,
        conLocations:state.conLocations
    };
};
```

Then in your view code, you can remove the button if the location is already added

```
{this.props.location.map((item,index)=>(
  <div key={index}>
    <div>
      <b>{item.mruCode} - {_labels[item.division]} - {item.country}</b>
      {!this.props.conLocations.find(item2 => item.mruCode === item2.mruCode) && (
        <div className="pull-right jd">
          <button
            className="call-to-action"
            onClick={()=>{this.handleClick(item.mruCode)}}
          >
            Add Location
          </button>
        </div>
      )}
      <hr/>
    </div>
  </div>
))}
```

Comment: thanks Tom for your response. my requirement is to hide the button only not the other property of that particular location. suppose list is like ( 1700 - World Industrial - US   (BUTTON) ) so after adding the objects to conLocation array that row is like ( 1700 - World Industrial - US   (No button)). hope you understand. is it possible to do by setState using mruCode ??

Comment: Since you have all your state in redux, you don't need your component to store any additional state. I updated my answer to show how to exclude the button for items already added.

Comment: hi tom it is not working. there is no error too. shall i upload full component code

Comment: i have added full code of component and included your edits too

Comment: I misread the reducer. The entire location object is stored in `conLocations`, not just the `mruCode`. I updated my answer to reflect that (replaced the `includes` with a `find` that matches on `mruCode`)

Comment: i have one more quick question. i have to retrieve some data based on dynamic id. I have opened a thread for that. If you have a look to suggest me what are the things i have missed here is the thread - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56660568/get-particular-location-details-based-on-jobid-in-redux/56661428?noredirect=1#comment99894081_56661428)